# Convert string with dashes to camelCase

Tags: php, string

I want to take a string like this: 'this-is-a-string' and convert it to this: 'thisIsAString':

```
function dashesToCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) {
    // Do stuff

    return $string;
}
```

I need to convert "kebab-case" to "camelCase".

Answer (score 231, accepted):

No regex or callbacks necessary. Almost all the work can be done with ucwords:

```
function dashesToCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) 
{

    $str = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));

    if (!$capitalizeFirstCharacter) {
        $str[0] = strtolower($str[0]);
    }

    return $str;
}

echo dashesToCamelCase('this-is-a-string');
```

If you're using PHP >= 5.3, you can use lcfirst instead of strtolower.

## Update

A second parameter was added to ucwords in PHP 5.4.32/5.5.16 which means we don't need to first change the dashes to spaces (thanks to Lars Ebert and PeterM for pointing this out). Here is the updated code:

```
function dashesToCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) 
{

    $str = str_replace('-', '', ucwords($string, '-'));

    if (!$capitalizeFirstCharacter) {
        $str = lcfirst($str);
    }

    return $str;
}

echo dashesToCamelCase('this-is-a-string');
```

Comment: `if (!$capitalizeFirstCharacter) {
        $str = lcfirst($str);
}`

Comment: Note that `ucwords` actually accepts a delimiter as second parameter (see [answer by PeterM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33122760/2580794)), so one of the `str_replace` calls would be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info @LarsEbert. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The condition can be rewritten with the usage of the ternary operator ```$str = ! $capitalizeFirstCharacter ? lcfirst($str) : $str;``` mainly for readability (though some may disagree) and/or reducing code complexity.

Answer (score 75):

This can be done very simply, by using [ucwords](http://php.net/ucwords) which accepts delimiter as param:

```
function camelize($input, $separator = '_')
{
    return lcfirst(str_replace($separator, '', ucwords($input, $separator)));
}
```

**NOTE:** Need php at least 5.4.32, 5.5.16

Comment: This will return something like CamelCase - if you want this to be something like camelCase then: `return str_replace($separator, '', lcfirst(ucwords($input, $separator)));`

Comment: `ucwords` has a second parameter `delimiter`, so `str_replace("_", "", ucwords($input, "_"));` is good enough (in most cases, :P

Comment: For clarity: the answer of [PeterM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5444623/peterm) will return *upper camel case* (= PascalCase). The comment of [Jeff S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670511/jeff-s) will return *lower camel case* (= dromedary case).

Comment: Either way. The OP needed a solution for kebab-case not snake_case.

Answer (score 14):

In Laravel use `Str::camel()`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$converted = Str::camel('foo_bar');

// fooBar
```

Answer (score 12):

Overloaded one-liner, with doc block...

```
/**
 * Convert underscore_strings to camelCase (medial capitals).
 *
 * @param {string} $str
 *
 * @return {string}
 */
function snakeToCamel ($str) {
  // Remove underscores, capitalize words, squash, lowercase first.
  return lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $str))));
}
```

Comment: This will return `null`

Comment: The function was lacking a `return` ...updated, thanks.  Here's a link to test this https://3v4l.org/YBHPd

Comment: How can we process for an array in one line ?

Comment: As demonstrated elsewhere on this page, `ucwords()` does not need `str_replace()` to be called inside of it.

Answer (score 10):

this is my variation on how to deal with it. Here I have two functions, first one **camelCase** turns anything into a camelCase and it wont mess if variable already contains cameCase. Second **uncamelCase** turns camelCase into underscore (great feature when dealing with database keys).

```
function camelCase($str) {
    $i = array("-","_");
    $str = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', "\\1 \\2", $str);
    $str = preg_replace('@[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_ ]+@', '', $str);
    $str = str_replace($i, ' ', $str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(strtolower($str)));
    $str = strtolower(substr($str,0,1)).substr($str,1);
    return $str;
}
function uncamelCase($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', "\\1_\\2", $str);
    $str = strtolower($str);
    return $str;
}
```

lets test both:

```
$camel = camelCase("James_LIKES-camelCase");
$uncamel = uncamelCase($camel);
echo $camel." ".$uncamel;
```

Comment: This function returns jamesLikesCameAse for camelCase instead of jamesLikesCameCase

Comment: @Alari [this demo](https://3v4l.org/9F3PB) proves your comment incorrect. Please remove your comment.

Comment: @mickmackusa Not true, please try again... lol, even in your demo - it does exactly what requested (Convert string with dashes to camelCase)

Comment: @Play You misunderstand, I am supporting your answer.  I am asking Alari to remove the false claim/comment.

Comment: If I am being honest, I don't find your `camelCase()` function to be elegant.  There are several other answers on this page that are written more directly/concisely.  There is a single native function to replace `strtolower(substr($str,0,1)).substr($str,1)`.  I do not endorse the single-use variable `$i`.  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is more simply written as `\w`.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, my bad... :) Well, either way (this was posted back in 2014) enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

I would probably use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), like this:

```
function dashesToCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) {
  return preg_replace_callback("/-[a-zA-Z]/", 'removeDashAndCapitalize', $string);
}

function removeDashAndCapitalize($matches) {
  return strtoupper($matches[0][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), you can use it like this :

```
$camelCase = preg_replace_callback('/-(.?)/', function($matches) {
     return ucfirst($matches[1]);
}, $dashes);
```

Answer (score 4):

here is very very easy solution in one line code

```
    $string='this-is-a-string' ;

   echo   str_replace('-', '', ucwords($string, "-"));
```

**output**                ThisIsAString

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```php
$var='snake_case';
$ucword= ucword($var,'_');
echo $ucword;
```

Output:

```
Snake_Case
```

remove _ with str_replace

```php
 str_replace('_','',$ucword); //SnakeCase
```

and result

```
 $result='SnakeCase';  //pascal case
 echo lcfirst('SnakeCase');  //snakeCase (camel case)
```

the important thing is the approach here I used snake case and camel case in the example

Comment: the path followed is important, not the solution itself

Comment: This late answer is only offering redundant advice and can be safely removed from the page.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = explode( "-", $string );
$first = true;
foreach( $string as &$v ) {
    if( $first ) {
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }
    $v = ucfirst( $v );
}
return implode( "", $string );
```

Untested code. Check the PHP docs for the functions im-/explode and ucfirst.

Answer (score 2):

One liner, PHP >= 5.3:

```
$camelCase = lcfirst(join(array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $url))));
```

Comment: please add some explanation how this can/will help the OP

Comment: This is the condensed version of @Victor's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The TurboCommons library contains a general purpose formatCase() method inside the StringUtils class, which lets you convert a string to lots of common case formats, like CamelCase, UpperCamelCase, LowerCamelCase, snake_case, Title Case, and many more.

https://github.com/edertone/TurboCommons

To use it, import the phar file to your project and:

```
use org\turbocommons\src\main\php\utils\StringUtils;

echo StringUtils::formatCase('sNake_Case', StringUtils::FORMAT_CAMEL_CASE);

// will output 'sNakeCase'
```

Here's the link to the method source code:

https://github.com/edertone/TurboCommons/blob/b2e015cf89c8dbe372a5f5515e7d9763f45eba76/TurboCommons-Php/src/main/php/utils/StringUtils.php#L653

Answer (score 2):

Try this ;)

```
$string = 'this-is-a-string';
$separator = '-';

$stringCamelize = str_replace(
    $separator,
    '',
    lcfirst(
        ucwords(
            strtolower($string),
            $separator
        )
    )
);

var_dump($stringCamelize); // -> 'thisIsAString'
```

Comment: What new value does this unexplained answer bring versus the many earlier posted techniques that make the same function calls?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you prefer not to deal with regex, and want to avoid **explicit** loops:

```
// $key = 'some-text', after transformation someText            
$key = lcfirst(implode('', array_map(function ($key) {
    return ucfirst($key);
}, explode('-', $key))));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function camelize($input, $separator = '_')
{
    return lcfirst(str_replace($separator, '', ucwords($input, $separator)));
}

echo ($this->camelize('someWeir-d-string'));
// output: 'someWeirdString';
```

Comment: Incomplete and incorrect code. Please test before posting.

Comment: I agree this is not a working demonstration. It will confuse researchers.  Plus this general technique existed earlier on this page.  I don't find this answer to add any new value to this page.

Answer (score 1):

Many good solutions above, and I can provide a different way that no one mention before. This example uses array.

```php
/**
 * Covert string with dashes into camel-case string.
 *
 * @param string $string A string with dashes.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getCamelCase(string $string = '')
{
    $str = explode('-', $string);
    $str = implode('', array_map(function($word) {
        return ucwords($word); 
    }, $str));

    return $str;
}
```

Test it:

```php
echo getCamelCase('This-is-example');
```

Result:

```
ThisIsExample
```

Comment: Almost. Stictly speaking that is PascalCase not camelCase. But we leave the correct solution as an excersise....

Answer (score 1):

Some very good solutions here. I compiled them together for easy c&p

```
declare(strict_types=1);
/**
 * convert kebab-case to PascalCase
 */
function kebabToPascal( string $str ): string {
   return str_replace( ' ', '', ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $str ) ) );
}

/**
 * convert snake_case to PascalCase
 */
function snakeToPascal( string $str ): string {
  return str_replace (' ', '', ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $str ) ) );
}

/**
  * convert snake_case to camelCase
  */
 function snakeToCamel( string $str ): string {
  return lcfirst( snakeToPascal( $str ) );
}

/**
 * convert kebab-case to camelCase
 */
function kebabToCamel( string $str): string {
  return lcfirst( kebabToPascal( $str ) );
}



echo snakeToCamel( 'snake_case' ). '<br>';
echo kebabToCamel( 'kebab-case' ). '<br>';
echo snakeToPascal( 'snake_case' ). '<br>';
echo kebabToPascal( 'kebab-case' ). '<br>';

echo kebabToPascal( 'It will BREAK on things-like_this' ). '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 you can use [`yii\helpers\Inflector::camelize()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-inflector#camelize()-detail):

```
use yii\helpers\Inflector;

echo Inflector::camelize("send_email");

// outputs: SendEmail
```

Yii provides a lot of similar functions, see [the Yii2 Docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-inflector#camelize()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

```
function camelCase($text) {
    return array_reduce(
         explode('-', strtolower($text)),
         function ($carry, $value) {
             $carry .= ucfirst($value);
             return $carry;
         },
         '');
}
```

Obviously, if another delimiter than '-', e.g. '_', is to be matched too, then this won't work, then a preg_replace could convert all (consecutive) delimiters to '-'  in $text first...

Comment: I don't really see how this is simpler, clearer or anyhow better than the solution provided (and accepted) about 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach:

```
$nasty = [' ', '-', '"', "'"]; // array of nasty characted to be removed
$cameled = lcfirst(str_replace($nasty, '', ucwords($string)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Laravel framework, you can use just [camel_case()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-camel-case) method.

```
camel_case('this-is-a-string') // 'thisIsAString'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
private function camelcase($input, $separator = '-')     
{
    $array = explode($separator, $input);

    $parts = array_map('ucwords', $array);

    return implode('', $parts);
}
```

Comment: Victor and @Tim already suggested this sequence of techniques (and finished by lowercasing the first letter).

Answer (score 0):

`$stringWithDash = 'Pending-Seller-Confirmation'; 
$camelize = str_replace('-', '', ucwords($stringWithDash, '-'));
echo $camelize;`

output: PendingSellerConfirmation

`ucwords` second(optional) parameter helps in identify a separator to camelize the string.
`str_replace` is used to finalize the output by removing the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small helper function using a functional [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) approach. 
Requires at least PHP 7.0

```
private function toCamelCase(string $stringToTransform, string $delimiter = '_'): string
{
    return array_reduce(
        explode($delimiter, $stringToTransform),
        function ($carry, string $part): string {
            return $carry === null ? $part: $carry . ucfirst($part);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private function dashesToCamelCase($string)
{
    $explode = explode('-', $string);
    $return = '';
    foreach ($explode as $item) $return .= ucfirst($item);

    return lcfirst($return);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function camelCase($string){
    $chunks = preg_split("/\s+|-|_/",$string);

    $camel = "";
        
    foreach ($chunks as $idx => $chunk){
         
        if ($idx===0){
            $camel = strtolower($chunk);
        }else{
                $camel .= ucfirst($chunk);
        }
    }
    return $camel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and most elegant solution would be:

```php
function dashesToCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) {
    $result = join("", array_map("ucfirst", explode("-", $string)));

    if ($capitalizeFirstCharacter === false) {
        return lcfirst($result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Line Option

```
echo str_replace(' ', '', lcfirst(ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", 'facebook_catalog_id_type')))); 
//output: facebookCatalogIdType
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 return preg_replace("/\-(.)/e", "strtoupper('\\1')", $string);
```

Comment: The /e modifier is deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: [More info about `e` modifier deprecation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval)

Answer (score -2):

This is simpler :

```
$string = preg_replace( '/-(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')", strtolower( $string ) );
```

Comment: The /e modifier is deprecated in PHP 5.5.