# PHP - preg_replace_callback for camelCasing

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-replace-callback, camelcasing

I have the following content

```
"aa_bb" : "foo"
"pp_Qq" : "bar"
"Xx_yY_zz" : "foobar"
```

And I want to convert the content on the left side to camelCase

```
"aaBb" : "foo"
"ppQq" : "bar"
"xxYyZz" : "foobar"
```

And the code:

```
// selects the left part
$newString = preg_replace_callback("/\"(.*?)\"(.*?):/", function($matches) {        
    // selects the characters following underscores
    $matches[1] = preg_replace_callback("/_(.?)/", function($matches) {
        //removes the underscore and uppercases the character
        return strtoupper($matches[1]);
    }, $matches[1]);

    // lowercases the first character before returning
    return "\"".lcfirst($matches[1])."\" : ".$matches[2];
}, $string);
```

**Can this code be simplified?**

Note: The content will always be a single string.

Comment: You can simplify your regex a bit, i.e [`^"([^"]+)"\s*:`](https://regex101.com/r/xYjDHv/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac I will try that out.

Comment: @user3783243 white spaces might not be consistent.

Comment: @user3783243 anywhere outside the quotes. No whitespace between the quotes for sure.

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry, misread your code. Also, the content will not be available as an array. Should have clarified it earlier. The content will be provided as string.

Comment: @user3783243 That seems doable but the after exploding, I will still need to recreate the string. Also your method only works for single underscore. I should update my question to reflect that.

Comment: @user3783243 BTW, thanks for your time. My requirements must be starting to annoy you haha.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2791998/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/31274782/2943403 , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48593/141885

Comment: Kindly explain where this data is headed (why you are bothering to do this).  Are you planning on calling `extract()` on these new keys? Do tell more -- there may be a more direct way of getting where you are going.

Comment: @Daol please dignify my request for clarification regarding your data and task.

Comment: @mickmackusa  sorry I didn’t really check the comments. As for your question, I don’t have control over where the data is coming from and where it will go, only thing that I have to deal with is to convert the contents to the required format

Comment: You don't know how it is going to be used?  Was this an interview or homework assignment?  Is the real data always consisting on simple, one-line string values? or are there fring cases to consider.

Comment: @mickmackusa neither, also the real data is string value. As far as I know there should be no other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you already have a working code you want to improve,  consider to post your question in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of stackoverflow next time.

Let's start to improve your original approach:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]*"\s*:~', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace_callback('~_+(.?)~', function ($n) {
        return strtoupper($n[1]);
    }, strtolower($m[0]));
}, $str);
```

**pro:** patterns are relatively simple and the idea is easy to understand.
**cons:** nested `preg_replace_callback`'s may hurt the eyes.

After this eyes warm-up exercice, we can try a `\G` based pattern approach:

```
$pattern = '~(?|\G(?!^)_([^_"]*)|("(?=[^"]*"\s*:)[^_"]*))~';
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    return ucfirst(strtolower($m[1]));
}, $str);
```

**pro:** the code is shorter, no need to use two `preg_replace_callback`'s.
**cons:** the pattern is from far more complicated.

notice: When you write a long pattern, nothing forbids to use the *free-spacing mode* with the x modifier and to put comments:

```
$pattern = '~
(?| # branch reset group: in which capture groups have the same number
    \G # contigous to the last successful match
    (?!^) # but not at the start of the string    
    _
    ( [^_"]* ) # capture group 1
  |
    ( # capture group 1
        "
        (?=[^"]*"\s*:) # lookahead to check if it is the "key part"
        [^_"]*
    )
)
~x';
```

Is there compromises between these two extremes, and what is the good one? Two suggestions:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]+"\s*:~', function ($m) {
    return array_reduce(explode('_', strtolower($m[0])), function ($c, $i) {
        return $c . ucfirst($i);
    });
}, $str);
```

**pro:** minimal use of regex.
**cons:** needs two callback functions except that this time the second one is called by `array_reduce` and not by `preg_replace_callback`.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~["_][^"_]*(?=[^"]*"\s*:)~', function ($m) {
    return ucfirst(strtolower(ltrim($m[0], '_')));
}, $str);
```

**pro:** the pattern is relatively simple and the callback function stays simple too. It looks like a good compromise.
**cons:** the pattern isn't very constrictive (but should suffice for your use case)

pattern description: the pattern looks for a _ or a " and matches following characters that aren't a _ or a ". A lookahead assertion then checks that these characters are inside the *key part* looking for a closing quote and colon. The match result is always like `_aBc` or `"aBc` (underscores are trimmed on the left in the callback function and `"` stays the same after applying `ucfirst`).

pattern details:

```
["_] # one " or _
[^"_]* # zero or more characters that aren't " or _
(?= # open a lookahead assertion (followed with)
    [^"]* # all that isn't a "
    " # a literal "
    \s* # eventual whitespaces
    : # a literal :
) # close the lookahead assertion
```

There's no good answer and what looks simple or complicated really depends on the reader.

Comment: Indeed. A simpler regex should be more maintainable for my use case. And the final method adds a decent balance between the two. If possible, could you add an explanation of the last regex to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You might make use of [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) in combination with the `\G` anchor and capturing groups.

```
(?:"\K([^_\r\n]+)|\G(?!^))(?=[^":\r\n]*")(?=[^:\r\n]*:)_?([a-zA-Z])([^"_\r\n]*)
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `"\K([^_\r\n]+)` Match `"`, capture **group 1** match 1+ times any char except _ or newline
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `(?=[^":\r\n]*")` Positive lookahead, assert `"`
- `(?=[^:\r\n]*:)` Positive lookahead, assert `:`
- `_?` Match optional _
- `([a-zA-Z])` Capture **group 2** match a-zA-Z
- `([^"_\r\n]*)` Capture **group 3** match 0+ times any char except _ or newline

In the replacement concatenate a combination of [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and [strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) using the 3 capturing groups.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyPsbW/1)

For example

```
$re = '/(?:"\K([^_\r\n]+)|\G(?!^))(?=[^":\r\n]*")(?=[^:\r\n]*:)_?([a-zA-Z])([^"_\r\n]*)/';
$str = '"aa_bb" : "foo"

"pp_Qq" : "bar"

"Xx_yY_zz" : "foobar"
"Xx_yYyyyyyYyY_zz_a" : "foobar"';

$result =  preg_replace_callback($re, function($matches) {
    return strtolower($matches[1]) . strtoupper($matches[2]) . strtolower($matches[3]);
}, $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
"aaBb" : "foo"

"ppQq" : "bar"

"xxYyZz" : "foobar"
"xxYyyyyyyyyyZzA" : "foobar"
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/7Nb7D)

Comment: Wow, that's quite the expression. I'll reply back once I check it out later

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I decided to go with the simpler regex solution in the end for the sake of maintainability.