# remove - and make every letter after as capital in the string - PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

input:

```
combined-interior
```

output:

```
combinedInterior
```

I have a string in PHP and I want to remove this character - and every letter after I should be big.

What I did till now:

```
$new_string = str_replace('-','',$orginal_string)
```

but this give me this output:

```
combinedinterior
```

any help?

Comment: The answer is available on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791998/convert-dashes-to-camelcase-in-php

Comment: ^ So it should be closed as a dupe then...

Comment: correct! thank you, should i close the question?

Comment: @ririririri - you can do yeah, SO is supposed to be canonical like that... the question might get closed as a dupe anyway though ;)